# ParameterException when spawning second Selenium Grid node as another process from Grid process programmatically

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-grid, java-threads

I'm setting up Selenium Grid which could spawn new instances of Nodes from HTTP Request on Grid Servlet endpoint: SpawnNodeServlet. That Servlet on GET request is creating new Selenium Grid Node with configuration to registry it to hub. By this I could add nodes when I want just by sending GET request under `http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/SpawnNodeServlet`. Everything works fine until I want to spawn second or next nodes. Only first one works properly, after that I got ParameterException (all codes below). Parameters should be fine, due to fact first node registering properly. Any ideas what could be wrong? I think, that trouble could be in process creation implementation.

I tried executing jars from Runtime exec as plain command but that also didn't work properly.

```java
final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
final Process command = runtime.exec(executionArgs.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Below is main code of `InstanceExecutor` which allow to create new Node instance:

```java
public class InstanceExecutor {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    private BufferedReader errorBufferedReader;
    private BufferedReader outputBufferedReader;
    private int exitValue;

    public void execute(List<String> args) throws InstanceExecutorException {

        final List<String> executionArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
        executionArgs.add(0, "java");
        executionArgs.addAll(args);

        try {
            final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(executionArgs.toArray(new String[0]));
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            logger.info("processBuilder.start()");

            this.errorBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            this.outputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            logger.info("BufferedReader's");

            process.waitFor();
            this.exitValue = process.exitValue();

            if (this.exitValue != 0) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to execute jar, " + this.getExecutionLog());
            }
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new InstanceExecutorException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getExecutionLog() {
        StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            while((line = this.errorBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                error
                    .append("\n")
                    .append(line);
            }
        } catch (final IOException ignored) { }

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while((line = this.outputBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output
                    .append("\n")
                    .append(line);
            }
        } catch (final IOException ignored) { }

        try {
            this.errorBufferedReader.close();
            this.outputBufferedReader.close();
        } catch (final IOException ignored) { }

        return "exitValue: " + this.exitValue + ", error: " + error + ", output: " + output;
    }
}
```

This class of `InstanceExecutor` is used in `doGet` of `SpawnNodeServlet`:

```java
public class SpawnNodeServlet extends RegistryBasedServlet {

    public SpawnNodeServlet() {
        this(null);
    }

    public SpawnNodeServlet(GridRegistry registry) {
        super(registry);
    }

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    private InstanceExecutor instanceExecutor = new InstanceExecutor();

    private final List<String> nodeArgs = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void sendResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setStatus(200);
        out.flush();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Spawning additional node");

        nodeArgs.add("-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"libs//chromedriver\"");
        nodeArgs.add("-cp");
        nodeArgs.add("hub/target/hub-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:node/target/node-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar");
        nodeArgs.add("org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3");
        nodeArgs.add("-role");
        nodeArgs.add("node");
        nodeArgs.add("-nodeConfig");
        nodeArgs.add("node/config.json");

        try {
            instanceExecutor.execute(nodeArgs);
        } catch (InstanceExecutorException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }

        sendResponse(response);
    }
}
```

This is console log after two times I executed GET request on `http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/SpawnNodeServlet`:

```
3:27:46.126 INFO [SpawnNodeServlet.doGet] - Spawning additional node
23:27:46.141 INFO [InstanceExecutor.execute] - processBuilder.start()
23:27:46.142 INFO [InstanceExecutor.execute] - BufferedReader's
23:27:47.018 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://169.254.168.67:8992
23:27:47.018 INFO [DefaultProxy.startPolling] - startPolling()
23:30:33.954 INFO [SpawnNodeServlet.doGet] - Spawning additional node
23:30:33.959 INFO [InstanceExecutor.execute] - processBuilder.start()
23:30:33.960 INFO [InstanceExecutor.execute] - BufferedReader's
2019-09-08 23:30:34.203:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp1128948651-14: /grid/admin/SpawnNodeServlet java.io.IOException: exception.InstanceExecutorException: java.io.IOException: Failed to execute jar, exitValue: 1, error:
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="libs//chromedriver"' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.initMainParameterValue(JCommander.java:936)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:752)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:340)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:319)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.parse(GridLauncherV3.java:218)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7(GridLauncherV3.java:271)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.lambda$launch$0(GridLauncherV3.java:86)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:86)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:70), output:
```

As you can see, first execution properly spawns Node, but second one, get this error.

How this process builder logic should be changed to not wait for process end (I tried to remove it and only create process but it also didn't work) and has ability to spawn more than 1 Selenium Grid Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SpawnNodeServlet you should remove class field nodeArgs, and define nodeArgs as local method variable.

You have instance field:

```
private final List<String> nodeArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After first service invocation list contains:

```
    "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"libs//chromedriver\""
    "-cp"
    "hub/target/hub-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:node/target/node-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
    "org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3"
    "-role"
    "node"
    "-nodeConfig"
    "node/config.json"
```

and after second invocation:

```
    "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"libs//chromedriver\""
    "-cp"
    "hub/target/hub-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:node/target/node-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
    "org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3"
    "-role"
    "node"
    "-nodeConfig"
    "node/config.json"
    "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"libs//chromedriver\""
    "-cp"
    "hub/target/hub-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:node/target/node-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
    "org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3"
    "-role"
    "node"
    "-nodeConfig"
    "node/config.json"
```

Then you are passing this list to the executor:

```
instanceExecutor.execute(nodeArgs);
```

And this is not valid java argument list.